# CSS: Push flex container item to next row on overflow

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, css-grid

I have a flex row with 2 divs (`.box-1 and .box-1`) both containing some content. What I would like is they both stay in the same row until the content in `.box-1` gets long enough to push `.box-2` to the next line.

`.box-2`

- Should have a fix width at a desktop screen size.
- Should be 50% width on tablet.
- Should be full width on mobile.

Right now as you can see from the snippet below the contents in `.box-2` will overflow but remain in the same line. **What I want is for `.box-2` to be pushed to a separate line when content overflows**. OR the miniumum width of `.box-2` to be wide enough to always hold the contents of my box.

NOTE: One issue I was facing using the `col-lg-3` class is that is will become too small for the contents of my `.box-2` at times.

I'm trying to use the css gird and stick with bootstrap classes for this. Trying to avoid custom styling as much as possible. The `.wrappable` class below is a standard in the library i'm using so can't be changed.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px; 
}

.wrappable {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
      margin-right: -0.625rem;
    margin-bottom: -0.625rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="wrappable">
  <div class="box-1 wrappable-flex border rounded item-1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, incididunt  ut labore et 
  </div>
  <div class="box-2 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 border rounded text-nowrap">
  some other text I want to put in the same row 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add to `.box-2` `min-width: fit-content;`

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px; 
}

.wrappable {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
      margin-right: -0.625rem;
    margin-bottom: -0.625rem;
}

.box-2 {
  min-width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="wrappable">
  <div class="box-1 wrappable-flex border rounded item-1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, incididunt  ut labore et 
  </div>
  <div class="box-2 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 border rounded text-nowrap">
  some other text I want to put in the same row 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Also learned `col-lg-auto` would effectively do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to stick to using bootstrap only classes and in my case a small change to the width classes helped.

So, I ended up changing `col-lg-3` to `col-lg-auto`. Fairly simple in hindsight. Found info on this from the [bootstrap site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#variable-width-content).

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px; 
}

.wrappable {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
      margin-right: -0.625rem;
    margin-bottom: -0.625rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="wrappable">
  <div class="box-1 wrappable-flex border rounded item-1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, incididunt  ut labore et 
  </div>
  <div class="box-2 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-auto border rounded text-nowrap">
  some other text I want to put in the same row 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```